# Is it harmful to plug a POE energized data source into non-POE NIC card?

Tags: power-over-ethernet

Some of our wired ethernet data connections are energized with [Power Over Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) at 48 volts.  But not all of our devices utilize POE.

Is it harmful to plug a device into POE when the device's NIC does not utilize POE?  I would like to use the wired ethernet connection for data on a device which does not utilize POE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

POE switches generally check if a device supports POE before sending power to it. If it doesn't, then no power is sent. You should be fine.

Comment: Ok, I believe you.  But could you provide a link to some supporting documentation or explain how this is done so I can feel comfortable with the answer?

Comment: This page has some information on the 802.3AF standard. The part you're interested in is "detection".

http://www.network-1.com/poe/poe_ovw.htm